# Why is $K\cdot f(n) + L \cdot g(n) \leq (K+L) \cdot (f(n) + g(n)) $?

Tags: algorithms

$K\cdot f(n) + L \cdot g(n) \leq (K+L) \cdot (f(n) + g(n)) $

$n, f(n), g(n),  K, L \in R^+$

I've seen this inequality a few times in my algorithms course, but I am trying to understand how it works. I would also like to know if it has a name.

An example of someone using it is in the solution to [R-3.16](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2011/05s1/tut/solutions/tut03sol.html)

Comment: Are $f, g$ functions into non-negative numbers, and $K, L$ non-negative numbers? Then simply expand the parentheses on the right hand side. You get the left hand side, plus something non-negative.

Comment: You are right, it is the case because of the context. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $K, L, f(n), g(n)$ are all non-negative numbers, expanding the right hand side of the inequality gives the left hand side plus something non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$(K+L).(f(n) + g(n)) = K.f(n) + L.g(n) + K.g(n) + L.f(n)$$

if $K.g(n) \geq 0$ and $L.f(n) \geq 0$ then they only increase the value of the RHS which makes it greater than or equal to the first two terms: $K.f(n) + L.g(n)$. Hence:
$$K.f(n) + L.g(n) \leq (K+L).(f(n) + g(n)) $$